# MS-ACCESS query to match only any N(consecutive) characters in string comparision

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, comparison

What query is suitable to compare two  tables specied below, however only part of string in     location(table1) will matches with the Location(table2).

```
Location(table1)    Location(table2)
india- north        USxcs
India-west          Indiaasd
India- east         Indiaavvds
India- south        Africassdcasv
US- north           Africavasvdsa
us-west             UKsacvavsdv
uk- east            Indiacascsa
uk- south           UScssca
Africa-middle       Indiacsasca
Africa-south        Africaccc
Africa-east         UKcac
```

1. only 1st two characters of location(table1) and 1st two characters of location(table2) should match. Please help
2. Any N(consecutive) characters of location(table1)and any N(consecutive) characters of location(table2)should match.

Comment: Your title says MS-SQL and your tags say MS Access. Please clarify.

Comment: Solutions in MS-SQl or MY-sql or MS ACCESS will help

Comment: The syntax varies across the various databases. The answer you said works for you would not work in a standard MS Access application.

Comment: OK remou, Then please provide Solution in MS-ACCESS.

Comment: Questions on Stackoverflow are supposed to have a "right" answer. If you do not specify a database, there can be no "right" answer, only a set of answers or a note on the general approach to such problems.

Comment: Actually i am trying for sloution on My-sql and MS-Access. as of now i am considering MS-ACeess.

Comment: in your question #2, when you say 'any two characters', do you mean 'any four characters'?

Comment: @beth i hope question #2 is clear in now

Comment: if what you're trying to do is extract meaning from garbage, you're going to have a hard time using an automated solution.  Can you use a set of known locations (india, uk, africa, austrail) and try to find matches in both tables independently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` for pattern-matching. The example below shows a list of location of table1 that has a partial match of locaton from table2

In MSSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM location_table2 a, location_table1 b
WHERE b.location LIKE a.Location + '%'
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM location_table2 a, location_table1 b
WHERE b.location LIKE CONCAT(a.Location, '%')
```

In MSAccess:

```
SELECT *
FROM location_table2 a, location_table1 b
WHERE a.Location LIKE LEFT(b.Location, InStr(b.Location, '-') -1) & '%'
```

Comment: @neobee i have added query for msaccess, hope it works now :D

Comment: Yes it works. how the same can be done for matching any four charcters in table1 and table2, where the location of characters need to match is unknown.

Comment: @neobee what do you mean by `matching any four charcters in table1 and tweo, where the location is unknown` can you elaborate more?

Comment: Suppose **abcaustrailaxyz** is one string in table1 and **aqwweaustricvb** is another string in table2, now **austri** is common in both the string. now need to match any minimum 4(consecutive) characters in strings while comparing table1 and table2

Comment: I think that is very difficult to do on access..it's beyond access functionality. Maybe you can do it in your application..

Answer (score 0):

In MSAccess, I would create 2 new queries introducing a new column with just the first 2 letters of the location field in each table, then add a third query joining those 2.

qry_table1:

```
select location as location1, left(location,2) as loc1 from table1
```

qry_table2:

```
select location as location2, left(location,2) as loc2 from table2
```

qry_join:

```
select location1, location2 
from qry_table1 inner join 
qry_table2 on 
qry_table1.loc1 = qry_table2.loc2
```

Comment: Yes it works. how the same can be done for matching any four charcters in table1 and table2, where the location of characters need to match is unknown.

Comment: that's a different question, requiring a different answer.  You couldn't use the same approach; you could try a full outer join and use the WHERE clause to check for rows like /*criteria*/ in table2, but the performance would suck rocks.